# Swift: How to turn Multiple Selection to Single Selection

Tags: swiftui, radio-group

Working on a single selection radio group and my code only produces Multi selection. The reason I'm using this way is that I want to store the selected value when the view is being changed and the user can comeback and see it.

my Model:

```
struct AssessmentModel: Identifiable {
   var id: Int
   var question: String
   var values: [Int]
   var options: [AssessmentOption]
}

struct AssessmentOption: Identifiable, Equatable {
   var id = UUID()
   var options: String
   var value: Int
   var isChecked = false
}

@Published var radioDataPage1: [AssessmentModel] = [
    AssessmentModel(id: 0, question: CRContent.depQuestion1, values: [], options: [
        AssessmentOption(options: CRContent.notAtAllText, value: 0),
        AssessmentOption(options: CRContent.severalDaysText, value: 1),
        AssessmentOption(options: CRContent.moreThanHalfText, value: 2),
        AssessmentOption(options: CRContent.nearlyEverydayText, value: 3),
    ]), ...
```

the function that makes the multi-selection

```
func selectedRowTapped2 (selectedQuestion: AssessmentModel, selectedRow: AssessmentOption) {

self.radioDataPage1[selectedQuestion.id].options[selectedRow.value].isChecked.toggle()
}
```

lastly is my view:

```
@EnvironmentObject var vm: CRAssessmentViewModel
@Binding var option: AssessmentOption?


var body: some View {
    ForEach(vm.radioDataPage1) { dep in
        MediumTextView(text: dep.question)
        
        ForEach(dep.options, id: \.id) { opt in
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: opt.isChecked ? "largecircle.fill.circle" : "circle"
                
                Text(opt.options)
            }
            .onTapGesture {
                vm.selectedRowTapped2(selectedQuestion: dep, selectedRow: opt)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

SO basically, I I have to check the id of my AssessmentModel and AssessmentOption, from which, I applied this logic:

```
func selectedRowTapped2(selectedRow: [AssessmentOption], id: Int, id2: Int) {
    var options = selectedRow
    for i in 0..<self.radioDataPage1.count {
        for index in 0..<options.count {
            if radioDataPage1[i].id == id && options[index].value == id2 {
                options[index].isChecked = true
            } else {
                options[index].isChecked = false
            }
            
            if radioDataPage1[i].id == id && options[index].value == id2 {
                radioDataPage1[i].options = options
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and onTapgesture:

```
vm.selectedRowTapped2(selectedRow: dep.options, id: dep.id, id2: opt.value)
```

still need to optimize it but this works for a form with tone of radio group question